# getting errors while trying to link one c file to another

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, linker

I am trying to separately compile each of the `c` file and then link them together as a single executable file. Following are the 2 `c` files :

*file1.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display();
int count;

int main() {
 printf("Inside the function main\n");
 count = 10;
 display();
}
```

*file2.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int count;
void display() {
  printf("Sunday mornings are beautiful !\n");
  printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

But when I try to compile them , I get some errors :

### When I compile file1.c

```
gcc file1.c -o file1
/tmp/ccV5kaGA.o: In function `main':
file1.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `display'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### When I compile file2.c

```
gcc file2.c -o file2
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/cczHziYd.o: In function `display':
file2.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `count'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What mistake am I committing ?

Comment: You're trying to link each separately. Forgive my CLI inexperience, but something like `gcc file1.c file2.c -o output` should do it.

Comment: Besides the above answer, you can use the gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o if you want to do the files individually and then link them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling each separately, but the problem is that you're also trying to link them separately.

```
gcc file1.c file2.c  -o theprogram   # compile and link both files
```

or:

```
gcc -c file1.c        # only compiles to file1.o
gcc -c file2.c        # only compiles to file2.o

gcc file1.o file2.o -o the program   # links them together
```

Comment: I thought when I will do `gcc file1.c -o file1` it will automatically search,compile and link _(file2.c)_ as a final `executable` with the name of `file1`

Comment: gcc file1.c -o file1 does not look at file2 at all.

Answer (score 2):

You must link them into a single executable.

```
gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -c file2.c -o file2.o
gcc file1.o file2.o -o theprogram
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here:

1) Compile both c files in one compilation unit. This means that each file is compiled and then they are immediately linked.

```
gcc file1.c file2.c -o program
```

The downside to this technique is that a change to either file will require complete recompilation from scratch. In a larger project, this could be a waste of time.

2) Use a .h file to declare the functions and include this .h file in both .c files. Be sure to #include your .h file in each .c file that invokes or implements its functions.

file1.h:

```
void display();
```

Then, **compile each .c file with the -c flag**. This prevents gcc from linking the code prematurely. Finally, link the two compiled files with gcc.

In summary:

```
gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -c file2.c -o file2.o
gcc file1.o file2.o -o myprogram
```

I would recommend taking a look at Makefiles, which can help you automate this process.